# How does android save files?

Tags: java, android, save

The saving and loading of files works fine, my issue isn't with that. What I'm confused about is how files are structured on the android system.

I'm using a listView to display my files. When I save files 1, 2, and 3, everything is fine. When I delete files 1 and 2 I only see file 3 and everything is fine. But then when I save files 4, 5, and 6, the listView reads out "4, 5, 3, 6".

What I think is happening is that Android will use up any available space is sees and save to that spot, so if I free up room by deleting 2 files, it won't move file 3 but instead leave 2 empty "blocks" where files 1 and 2 were. These blocks are filled when files 4 and 5 are saved and that's why it's loaded in that order.

Again, this is just a hunch. I was just wondering if anybody knew anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

The ListView order is handled by an adapter. Based on the adapter you use the ListView order will be different.

I'm guessing you used a standard ListView adapter (CurrorAdapter or ListAdatper) that support basic sorting if you would like to order the list in a particular way. Otherwise you could or might need to write your own adapter to have custom behavior by extending Adaptor or ListAdapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html.

Comment: Right, I guess I'm more curious as to why the files are ordered like this to begin with.  It seems like android doesn't alphabetize their files and that seemed odd to me.  The files are name file1, file2, etc. and I'm displaying them in the order they are read in.  It was just surprising.